# RSpec test failed find user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

My Controller (User Controller)

```
 def reset_password
      @user = User.find_by_reset_code(params[:reset_code]) unless params[:reset_code].nil?     

      if request.post?    
        if @user && @user.update_attributes(:password => params[:user][:password], :password_confirmation => params[:user][:password_confirmation])
          self.current_user = @user
          @user.delete_reset_code
          flash[:success] = t('helpers.password_reset_successful')
          render :template => "sessions/new"
        else
          flash[:error] = t('helpers.password_reset_error')
          redirect_to root_path
        end
      end
   end
```

I would like test it and I do...

```
   it "POST 'reset password with reset code page'" do
        @user.reset_code = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest( Time.now.to_s.split(//).sort_by {rand}.join )

        User.should_receive(:find_by_reset_code).with(@user.reset_code)
        post :reset_password, :user => {"id" => @user.id}
      end
```

But I've exception in Rspec -

```
Failure/Error: User.should_receive(:find_by_reset_code).with(@user.reset_code)
       (<User(id: integer, name: string, email: string, encrypted_password: string, salt: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, admin: boolean, reset_code: string) (class)>).find_by_reset_code("acd8a322d9554fbde375f5c39446276188a41678")
           expected: 1 time
           received: 0 times
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `reset_code` param in your request.

Replace with:

```
post :reset_password, :reset_code => @user.reset_code
```

And you'd rather do:

```
User.should_receive(:find_by_reset_code).with(@user.reset_code).and_return @user
```

Comment: User.should_receive(:find_by_reset_code).with(@user.reset_code)